# extract specific key/value from a 2d array of dictionaries

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, 2d

I have a 2d array of dictionaries from which I want extract the first value of the first key meeting specific criteria and put them in another 2d array. Here is the matrix "coord_curva_testo" (partial):

```
[[{1: 0}, {2: 1}, {3: 2}, {3: 3}, {4: 4}, {5: 5}, {6: 6}, {6: 7}, {6: 8}, {7: 9}, {8: 10}, {8: 11}, {8: 12}, {8: 13}, {8: 14}, {8: 15}, {8: 16}, {8: 17}, {8: 18}, {8: 19}, {8: 20}, {9: 21}, {9: 22}, {9: 23}, {10: 24}, {10: 25}, {11: 26}, {11: 27}, {11: 28}, {11: 29}, {12: 30}, {12: 31}, {12: 32}, {12: 33}, {12: 34}, {13: 35}, {13: 36}, {13: 37}, {14: 38}, {15: 39}, {15: 40}, {15: 41}, {15: 42}, {15: 43}, {15: 44}, {15: 45}, {15: 46}, {15: 47}, {15: 48}, {15: 49}, {15: 50}, {15: 51}, {15: 52}, {15: 53}, {15: 54}, {15: 55}, {15: 56}, {15: 57}, {15: 58}], [{1: 0}, {2: 1}, {3: 2}, {4: 3}, {5: 4}, {6: 5}, {6: 6}, {6: 7}, {7: 8}, {8: 9}, {8: 10}, {8: 11}, {8: 12}, {8: 13}, {8: 14}, {8: 15}, {8: 16}, {8: 17}, {8: 18}, {8: 19}, {9: 20}, {9: 21}, {9: 22}, {10: 23}, {10: 24}, {11: 25}, {11: 26}, {11: 27}, {11: 28}, {12: 29}, {12: 30}, {12: 31}, {12: 32}, {12: 33}, {13: 34}, {13: 35}, {13: 36}, {14: 37}, {15: 38}, {15: 39}, {15: 40}, {15: 41}, {15: 42}, {15: 43}, {15: 44}, {15: 45}, {15: 46}, {15: 47}, {15: 48}, {15: 49}, {15: 50}, {15: 51}, {15: 52}, {15: 53}, {15: 54}, {15: 55}, {15: 56}, {15: 57}], [{1: 0}, {2: 1}, {3: 2}, {4: 3}, {5: 4}, {5: 5}, {5: 6}, {6: 7}, {7: 8}, {7: 9}, {7: 10}, {7: 11}, {8: 12}, {8: 13}, {8: 14}, {8: 15}, {8: 16}, {8: 17}, {8: 18}, {9: 19}, {9: 20}, {9: 21}, {10: 22}, {10: 23}, {11: 24}, {11: 25}, {11: 26}, {11: 27}, {12: 28}, {12: 29}, {12: 30}, {12: 31}, {12: 32}, {13: 33}, {13: 34}, {13: 35}, {14: 36}, {15: 37}, {15: 38}, {15: 39}, {15: 40}, {15: 41}, {15: 42}, {15: 43}, {15: 44}, {15: 45}, {15: 46}, {15: 47}, {15: 48}, {15: 49}, {15: 50}, {15: 51}, {15: 52}, {15: 53}, {15: 54}, {15: 55}, {15: 56}], [{1: 0}, {2: 1}, {3: 2}, {4: 3}, {5: 4}, {5: 5}, {6: 6}, {7: 7}, {7: 8}, {7: 9}, {7: 10}, {8: 11}, {8: 12}, {8: 13}, {8: 14}, {8: 15}, {8: 16}, {8: 17}, {9: 18}, {9: 19}, {9: 20}, {10: 21}, {10: 22}, {11: 23}, {11: 24}, {11: 25}, {11: 26}, {12: 27}, {12: 28}, {12: 29}, {12: 30}, {12: 31}, {13: 32}, {13: 33}, {13: 34}, {14: 35}, {15: 36}, {15: 37}, {15: 38}, {15: 39}, {15: 40}, {15: 41}, {15: 42}, {15: 43}, {15: 44}, {15: 45}, {15: 46}, {15: 47}, {15: 48}, {15: 49}, {15: 50}, {15: 51}, {15: 52}, {15: 53}, {15: 54}, {15: 55}], [{1: 0}, {2: 1}, {3: 2}, {4: 3}, {5: 4}, {6: 5}, {7: 6}, {7: 7}, {7: 8}, {7: 9}, {8: 10}, {8: 11}, {8: 12}, {8: 13}, {8: 14}, {8: 15}, {8: 16}, {9: 17}, {9: 18}, {9: 19}, {10: 20}, {10: 21}, {11: 22}, {11: 23}, {11: 24}, {11: 25}, {12: 26}, {12: 27}, {12: 28}, {12: 29}, {12: 30}, {13: 31}, {13: 32}, {13: 33}, {14: 34}, {15: 35}, {15: 36}, {15: 37}, {15: 38}, {15: 39}, {15: 40}, {15: 41}, {15: 42}, {15: 43}, {15: 44}, {15: 45}, {15: 46}, {15: 47}, {15: 48}, {15: 49}, {15: 50}, {15: 51}, {15: 52}, {15: 53}, {15: 54}], [{1: 0}, {2: 1}, {3: 2}, {4: 3}, {5: 4}, {6: 5}, {6: 6}, {6: 7}, {6: 8}, {7: 9}, {7: 10}, {7: 11}, {8: 12}, {8: 13}, {8: 14}, {8: 15}, {9: 16}, {9: 17}, {9: 18}, {10: 19}, {10: 20}, {11: 21}, {11: 22}, {11: 23}, {11: 24}, {12: 25}, {12: 26}, {12: 27}, {12: 28}, {12: 29}, {13: 30}, {13: 31}, {13: 32}, {14: 33}, {15: 34}, {15: 35}, {15: 36}, {15: 37}, {15: 38}, {15: 39}, {15: 40}, {15: 41}, {15: 42}, {15: 43}, {15: 44}, {15: 45}, {15: 46}, {15: 47}, {15: 48}, {15: 49}, {15: 50}, {15: 51}, {15: 52}, {15: 53}], [{1: 0}, {2: 1}, {3: 2}, {4: 3}, {5: 4}, {5: 5}, {5: 6}, {5: 7}, {6: 8}, {6: 9}, {6: 10}, {7: 11}, {7: 12}, {7: 13}, {7: 14}, {8: 15}, {8: 16}, {8: 17}, {9: 18}, {9: 19}, {10: 20}, {10: 21}, {10: 22}, {10: 23}, {11: 24}, {11: 25}, {11: 26}, {11: 27}, {11: 28}, {12: 29}, {12: 30}, {12: 31}, {13: 32}, {14: 33}, {14: 34}, {14: 35}, {14: 36}, {14: 37}, {14: 38}, {14: 39}, {14: 40}, {14: 41}, {14: 42}, {14: 43}, {14: 44}, {14: 45}, {14: 46}, {14: 47}, {14: 48}, {14: 49}, {14: 50}, {14: 51}, {14: 52}], [{1: 0}, {2: 1}, {3: 2}, {4: 3}, {5: 4}, {5: 5}, {5: 6}, {6: 7}, {6: 8}, {6: 9}, {7: 10}, {7: 11}, {7: 12}, {7: 13}, {8: 14}, {8: 15}, {8: 16}, {9: 17}, {9: 18}, {10: 19}, {10: 20}, {10: 21}, {10: 22}, {11: 23}, {11: 24}, {11: 25}, {11: 26}, {11: 27}, {12: 28}, {12: 29}, {12: 30}, {13: 31}, {14: 32}, {14: 33}, {14: 34}, {14: 35}, {14: 36}, {14: 37}, {14: 38}, {14: 39}, {14: 40}, {14: 41}, {14: 42}, {14: 43}, {14: 44}, {14: 45}, {14: 46}, {14: 47}, {14: 48}, {14: 49}, {14: 50}, {14: 51}], [{1: 0}, {2: 1}, {3: 2}, {4: 3}, {4: 4}, {4: 5}, {5: 6}, {6: 7}, {6: 8}, {7: 9}, {7: 10}, {7: 11}, {7: 12}, {8: 13}, {8: 14}, {8: 15}, {9: 16}, {9: 17}, {10: 18}, {10: 19}, {10: 20}, {10: 21}, {11: 22}, {11: 23}, {11: 24}, {11: 25}, {11: 26}, {12: 27}, {12: 28}, {12: 29}, {13: 30}, {14: 31}, {14: 32}, {14: 33}, {14: 34}, {14: 35}, {14: 36}, {14: 37}, {14: 38}, {14: 39}, {14: 40}, {14: 41}, {14: 42}, {14: 43}, {14: 44}, {14: 45}, {14: 46}, {14: 47}, {14: 48}, {14: 49}, {14: 50}], [{1: 0}, {2: 1}, {3: 2}, {3: 3}, {4: 4}, {5: 5}, {6: 6}, {6: 7}, {7: 8}, {7: 9}, {7: 10}, {7: 11}, {8: 12}, {8: 13}, {8: 14}, {9: 15}, {9: 16}, {10: 17}, {10: 18}, {10: 19}, {10: 20}, {11: 21}, {11: 22}, {11: 23}, {11: 24}, {11: 25}, {12: 26}, {12: 27}, {12: 28}, {13: 29}, {14: 30}, {14: 31}, {14: 32}, {14: 33}, {14: 34}, {14: 35}, {14: 36}, {14: 37}, {14: 38}, {14: 39}, {14: 40}, {14: 41}, {14: 42}, {14: 43}, {14: 44}, {14: 45}, {14: 46}, {14: 47}, {14: 48}, {14: 49}], [{1: 0}, {2: 1}, {2: 2}, {3: 3}, {4: 4}, {5: 5}, {5: 6}, {6: 7}, {6: 8}, {6: 9}, {6: 10}, {7: 11}, {7: 12}, {7: 13}, {8: 14}, {8: 15}, {9: 16}, {9: 17}, {9: 18}, {9: 19}, {10: 20}, {10: 21}, {10: 22}, {10: 23}, {10: 24}, {11: 25}, {12: 26}, {12: 27}, {13: 28}, {14: 29}, {14: 30}, {14: 31}, {14: 32}, {14: 33}, {14: 34}, {14: 35}, {14: 36}, {14: 37}, {14: 38}, {14: 39}, {14: 40}, {14: 41}, {14: 42}, {14: 43}, {14: 44}, {14: 45}, {14: 46}, {14: 47}, {14: 48}], [{1: 0}, {1: 1}, {2: 2}, {3: 3}, {4: 4}, {4: 5}, {5: 6}, {5: 7}, {5: 8}, {5: 9}, {6: 10}, {6: 11}, {6: 12}, {7: 13}, {7: 14}, {8: 15}, {8: 16}, {9: 17}, {9: 18}, {10: 19}, {10: 20}, {10: 21}, {10: 22}, {10: 23}, {11: 24}, {12: 25}, {12: 26}, {13: 27}, {14: 28}, {14: 29}, {14: 30}, {14: 31}, {14: 32}, {14: 33}, {14: 34}, {14: 35}, {14: 36}, {14: 37}, {14: 38}, {14: 39}, {14: 40}, {14: 41}, {14: 42}, {14: 43}, {14: 44}, {14: 45}, {14: 46}, {14: 47}]]
```

I wanted to extract for every row the first dictionary with key 8, or 10 or 12 and from each of these keys extract only the first value. For instance in the first row the couple are (8,10), (10, 24) and (12,30).

I am new to Python which I find the best language for my purposes and here is my code (sorry if you will find it a bit messy):

```
dict_rep = defaultdict(list)
line_plot= [[]]

move = 0

key_num = [8,10,12]

for move in range(len(coord_curva_testo[move])):

    for d in coord_curva_testo[move]: 

        for key, value in d.items():

            if key in key_num:

                dict_rep[key].append(value +1)

    line_plot[move].append({list(dict_rep.items([0][0]:list(dict_rep.values())[0][0]})

    line_plot[move].append({list(dict_rep.items()[1][0]:list(dict_rep.values())[1][0]})

    line_plot[move].append({list(dict_rep.items())[2][0]:list(dict_rep.values())[2][0]})
    curva_plot.append([])
```

But the result is that every row has the same dictionaries of the first one.

```
[[{8: 10}, {10: 24}, {12: 30}], [{8: 10}, {10: 24}, {12: 30}], [{8: 10}, {10: 24}, {12: 30}], [{8: 10}, {10: 24}, {12: 30}], [{8: 10}, {10: 24}, {12: 30}], [{8: 10}, {10: 24}, {12: 30}], [{8: 10}, {10: 24}, {12: 30}], [{8: 10}, {10: 24}, {12: 30}], [{8: 10}, {10: 24}, {12: 30}], [{8: 10}, {10: 24}, {12: 30}], [{8: 10}, {10: 24}, {12: 30}], [{8: 10}, {10: 24}, {12: 30}], [{8: 10}, {10: 24}, {12: 30}], [{8: 10}, {10: 24}, {12: 30}], [{8: 10}, {10: 24}, {12: 30}], [{8: 10}, {10: 24}, {12: 30}], [{8: 10}, {10: 24}, {12: 30}], [{8: 10}, {10: 24}, {12: 30}], [{8: 10}, {10: 24}, {12: 30}], [{8: 10}, {10: 24}, {12: 30}], [{8: 10}, {10: 24}, {12: 30}], [{8: 10}, {10: 24}, {12: 30}], [{8: 10}, {10: 24}, {12: 30}], [{8: 10}, {10: 24}, {12: 30}], [{8: 10}, {10: 24}, {12: 30}], [{8: 10}, {10: 24}, {12: 30}], [{8: 10}, {10: 24}, {12: 30}], [{8: 10}, {10: 24}, {12: 30}], [{8: 10}, {10: 24}, {12: 30}], [{8: 10}, {10: 24}, {12: 30}], [{8: 10}, {10: 24}, {12: 30}], [{8: 10}, {10: 24}, {12: 30}], [{8: 10}, {10: 24}, {12: 30}], [{8: 10}, {10: 24}, {12: 30}], [{8: 10}, {10: 24}, {12: 30}], [{8: 10}, {10: 24}, {12: 30}], [{8: 10}, {10: 24}, {12: 30}], [{8: 10}, {10: 24}, {12: 30}], [{8: 10}, {10: 24}, {12: 30}], [{8: 10}, {10: 24}, {12: 30}], [{8: 10}, {10: 24}, {12: 30}]
```

Can anyone help and explain me were I am wrong and drive me to the good solution for my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Is this the format you're after?

```
a = [[{1: 0}, {2: 1}, {3: 2}, {3: 3}, {4: 4}, {5: 5}, {6: 6}, {6: 7}, {6: 8}, {7: 9}, {8: 10}, {8: 11}, {8: 12}, {8: 13}, {8: 14}, {8: 15}, {8: 16}, {8: 17}, {8: 18}, {8: 19}, {8: 20}, {9: 21}, {9: 22}, {9: 23}, {10: 24}, {10: 25}, {11: 26}, {11: 27}, {11: 28}, {11: 29}, {12: 30}, {12: 31}, {12: 32}, {12: 33}, {12: 34}, {13: 35}, {13: 36}, {13: 37}, {14: 38}, {15: 39}, {15: 40}, {15: 41}, {15: 42}, {15: 43}, {15: 44}, {15: 45}, {15: 46}, {15: 47}, {15: 48}, {15: 49}, {15: 50}, {15: 51}, {15: 52}, {15: 53}, {15: 54}, {15: 55}, {15: 56}, {15: 57}, {15: 58}], [{1: 0}, {2: 1}, {3: 2}, {4: 3}, {5: 4}, {6: 5}, {6: 6}, {6: 7}, {7: 8}, {8: 9}, {8: 10}, {8: 11}, {8: 12}, {8: 13}, {8: 14}, {8: 15}, {8: 16}, {8: 17}, {8: 18}, {8: 19}, {9: 20}, {9: 21}, {9: 22}, {10: 23}, {10: 24}, {11: 25}, {11: 26}, {11: 27}, {11: 28}, {12: 29}, {12: 30}, {12: 31}, {12: 32}, {12: 33}, {13: 34}, {13: 35}, {13: 36}, {14: 37}, {15: 38}, {15: 39}, {15: 40}, {15: 41}, {15: 42}, {15: 43}, {15: 44}, {15: 45}, {15: 46}, {15: 47}, {15: 48}, {15: 49}, {15: 50}, {15: 51}, {15: 52}, {15: 53}, {15: 54}, {15: 55}, {15: 56}, {15: 57}], [{1: 0}, {2: 1}, {3: 2}, {4: 3}, {5: 4}, {5: 5}, {5: 6}, {6: 7}, {7: 8}, {7: 9}, {7: 10}, {7: 11}, {8: 12}, {8: 13}, {8: 14}, {8: 15}, {8: 16}, {8: 17}, {8: 18}, {9: 19}, {9: 20}, {9: 21}, {10: 22}, {10: 23}, {11: 24}, {11: 25}, {11: 26}, {11: 27}, {12: 28}, {12: 29}, {12: 30}, {12: 31}, {12: 32}, {13: 33}, {13: 34}, {13: 35}, {14: 36}, {15: 37}, {15: 38}, {15: 39}, {15: 40}, {15: 41}, {15: 42}, {15: 43}, {15: 44}, {15: 45}, {15: 46}, {15: 47}, {15: 48}, {15: 49}, {15: 50}, {15: 51}, {15: 52}, {15: 53}, {15: 54}, {15: 55}, {15: 56}], [{1: 0}, {2: 1}, {3: 2}, {4: 3}, {5: 4}, {5: 5}, {6: 6}, {7: 7}, {7: 8}, {7: 9}, {7: 10}, {8: 11}, {8: 12}, {8: 13}, {8: 14}, {8: 15}, {8: 16}, {8: 17}, {9: 18}, {9: 19}, {9: 20}, {10: 21}, {10: 22}, {11: 23}, {11: 24}, {11: 25}, {11: 26}, {12: 27}, {12: 28}, {12: 29}, {12: 30}, {12: 31}, {13: 32}, {13: 33}, {13: 34}, {14: 35}, {15: 36}, {15: 37}, {15: 38}, {15: 39}, {15: 40}, {15: 41}, {15: 42}, {15: 43}, {15: 44}, {15: 45}, {15: 46}, {15: 47}, {15: 48}, {15: 49}, {15: 50}, {15: 51}, {15: 52}, {15: 53}, {15: 54}, {15: 55}], [{1: 0}, {2: 1}, {3: 2}, {4: 3}, {5: 4}, {6: 5}, {7: 6}, {7: 7}, {7: 8}, {7: 9}, {8: 10}, {8: 11}, {8: 12}, {8: 13}, {8: 14}, {8: 15}, {8: 16}, {9: 17}, {9: 18}, {9: 19}, {10: 20}, {10: 21}, {11: 22}, {11: 23}, {11: 24}, {11: 25}, {12: 26}, {12: 27}, {12: 28}, {12: 29}, {12: 30}, {13: 31}, {13: 32}, {13: 33}, {14: 34}, {15: 35}, {15: 36}, {15: 37}, {15: 38}, {15: 39}, {15: 40}, {15: 41}, {15: 42}, {15: 43}, {15: 44}, {15: 45}, {15: 46}, {15: 47}, {15: 48}, {15: 49}, {15: 50}, {15: 51}, {15: 52}, {15: 53}, {15: 54}], [{1: 0}, {2: 1}, {3: 2}, {4: 3}, {5: 4}, {6: 5}, {6: 6}, {6: 7}, {6: 8}, {7: 9}, {7: 10}, {7: 11}, {8: 12}, {8: 13}, {8: 14}, {8: 15}, {9: 16}, {9: 17}, {9: 18}, {10: 19}, {10: 20}, {11: 21}, {11: 22}, {11: 23}, {11: 24}, {12: 25}, {12: 26}, {12: 27}, {12: 28}, {12: 29}, {13: 30}, {13: 31}, {13: 32}, {14: 33}, {15: 34}, {15: 35}, {15: 36}, {15: 37}, {15: 38}, {15: 39}, {15: 40}, {15: 41}, {15: 42}, {15: 43}, {15: 44}, {15: 45}, {15: 46}, {15: 47}, {15: 48}, {15: 49}, {15: 50}, {15: 51}, {15: 52}, {15: 53}], [{1: 0}, {2: 1}, {3: 2}, {4: 3}, {5: 4}, {5: 5}, {5: 6}, {5: 7}, {6: 8}, {6: 9}, {6: 10}, {7: 11}, {7: 12}, {7: 13}, {7: 14}, {8: 15}, {8: 16}, {8: 17}, {9: 18}, {9: 19}, {10: 20}, {10: 21}, {10: 22}, {10: 23}, {11: 24}, {11: 25}, {11: 26}, {11: 27}, {11: 28}, {12: 29}, {12: 30}, {12: 31}, {13: 32}, {14: 33}, {14: 34}, {14: 35}, {14: 36}, {14: 37}, {14: 38}, {14: 39}, {14: 40}, {14: 41}, {14: 42}, {14: 43}, {14: 44}, {14: 45}, {14: 46}, {14: 47}, {14: 48}, {14: 49}, {14: 50}, {14: 51}, {14: 52}], [{1: 0}, {2: 1}, {3: 2}, {4: 3}, {5: 4}, {5: 5}, {5: 6}, {6: 7}, {6: 8}, {6: 9}, {7: 10}, {7: 11}, {7: 12}, {7: 13}, {8: 14}, {8: 15}, {8: 16}, {9: 17}, {9: 18}, {10: 19}, {10: 20}, {10: 21}, {10: 22}, {11: 23}, {11: 24}, {11: 25}, {11: 26}, {11: 27}, {12: 28}, {12: 29}, {12: 30}, {13: 31}, {14: 32}, {14: 33}, {14: 34}, {14: 35}, {14: 36}, {14: 37}, {14: 38}, {14: 39}, {14: 40}, {14: 41}, {14: 42}, {14: 43}, {14: 44}, {14: 45}, {14: 46}, {14: 47}, {14: 48}, {14: 49}, {14: 50}, {14: 51}], [{1: 0}, {2: 1}, {3: 2}, {4: 3}, {4: 4}, {4: 5}, {5: 6}, {6: 7}, {6: 8}, {7: 9}, {7: 10}, {7: 11}, {7: 12}, {8: 13}, {8: 14}, {8: 15}, {9: 16}, {9: 17}, {10: 18}, {10: 19}, {10: 20}, {10: 21}, {11: 22}, {11: 23}, {11: 24}, {11: 25}, {11: 26}, {12: 27}, {12: 28}, {12: 29}, {13: 30}, {14: 31}, {14: 32}, {14: 33}, {14: 34}, {14: 35}, {14: 36}, {14: 37}, {14: 38}, {14: 39}, {14: 40}, {14: 41}, {14: 42}, {14: 43}, {14: 44}, {14: 45}, {14: 46}, {14: 47}, {14: 48}, {14: 49}, {14: 50}], [{1: 0}, {2: 1}, {3: 2}, {3: 3}, {4: 4}, {5: 5}, {6: 6}, {6: 7}, {7: 8}, {7: 9}, {7: 10}, {7: 11}, {8: 12}, {8: 13}, {8: 14}, {9: 15}, {9: 16}, {10: 17}, {10: 18}, {10: 19}, {10: 20}, {11: 21}, {11: 22}, {11: 23}, {11: 24}, {11: 25}, {12: 26}, {12: 27}, {12: 28}, {13: 29}, {14: 30}, {14: 31}, {14: 32}, {14: 33}, {14: 34}, {14: 35}, {14: 36}, {14: 37}, {14: 38}, {14: 39}, {14: 40}, {14: 41}, {14: 42}, {14: 43}, {14: 44}, {14: 45}, {14: 46}, {14: 47}, {14: 48}, {14: 49}], [{1: 0}, {2: 1}, {2: 2}, {3: 3}, {4: 4}, {5: 5}, {5: 6}, {6: 7}, {6: 8}, {6: 9}, {6: 10}, {7: 11}, {7: 12}, {7: 13}, {8: 14}, {8: 15}, {9: 16}, {9: 17}, {9: 18}, {9: 19}, {10: 20}, {10: 21}, {10: 22}, {10: 23}, {10: 24}, {11: 25}, {12: 26}, {12: 27}, {13: 28}, {14: 29}, {14: 30}, {14: 31}, {14: 32}, {14: 33}, {14: 34}, {14: 35}, {14: 36}, {14: 37}, {14: 38}, {14: 39}, {14: 40}, {14: 41}, {14: 42}, {14: 43}, {14: 44}, {14: 45}, {14: 46}, {14: 47}, {14: 48}], [{1: 0}, {1: 1}, {2: 2}, {3: 3}, {4: 4}, {4: 5}, {5: 6}, {5: 7}, {5: 8}, {5: 9}, {6: 10}, {6: 11}, {6: 12}, {7: 13}, {7: 14}, {8: 15}, {8: 16}, {9: 17}, {9: 18}, {10: 19}, {10: 20}, {10: 21}, {10: 22}, {10: 23}, {11: 24}, {12: 25}, {12: 26}, {13: 27}, {14: 28}, {14: 29}, {14: 30}, {14: 31}, {14: 32}, {14: 33}, {14: 34}, {14: 35}, {14: 36}, {14: 37}, {14: 38}, {14: 39}, {14: 40}, {14: 41}, {14: 42}, {14: 43}, {14: 44}, {14: 45}, {14: 46}, {14: 47}]]

rv = []
for r in a:
    ret = []
    for i in [8, 10, 12]:
        ret.append(next(d for d in r if i in d))
    rv.append(ret)
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
rv = [[next(d for d in r if i in d) for i in [8, 10, 12]] for r in a]
```

**Output:**

```
>>> rv
[[{8: 10}, {10: 24}, {12: 30}],
 [{8: 9}, {10: 23}, {12: 29}],
 [{8: 12}, {10: 22}, {12: 28}],
 [{8: 11}, {10: 21}, {12: 27}],
 [{8: 10}, {10: 20}, {12: 26}],
 [{8: 12}, {10: 19}, {12: 25}],
 [{8: 15}, {10: 20}, {12: 29}],
 [{8: 14}, {10: 19}, {12: 28}],
 [{8: 13}, {10: 18}, {12: 27}],
 [{8: 12}, {10: 17}, {12: 26}],
 [{8: 14}, {10: 20}, {12: 26}],
 [{8: 15}, {10: 19}, {12: 25}]]
```

Comment: Hi CDJB,thanks for the solution. I was working about it because there are dictionaries in which key 12 is absent. So I wonder  how to modify the onliner for loop.

Comment: You could just wrap the ret.append line in a try: except: pass statement - if no dictionary has a key of 12 then it will just skip that key value.